# Django mod_wsgi Hosting Server Requirements

Tags: django, apache, webserver, mod-wsgi, web-hosting

I have normal Content Management Website developed in Django. My Client has a server with `256 MB RAM`. He wants to deploy this site in wsgi  mode. 256 MB RAM is sufficient or not?
I don't have any knowledge about Server RAM requirements and all. Any help will be appreciated

I have gone through this doc of [wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)
But it doesn't have any info about system Specifications.

What is the minmum RAM needed for running a Django application in wsgi mode?

Answer (score 3):

How much memory you need depends on how many instances of the web application you intend to run at the same time. How many you need is going to be dictated by factors such as whether your code base is thread safe and so whether you can run it in a multithreaded configuration, or whether you will have to run a multi process configuration with single threaded processes.

So, do you even know how much memory one instance (process) uses when it is running your application?

The underlying web server has very little to do with memory used, because your application is going to totally dwarf how much memory the web server uses.

Some quick tips.

- Don't use embedded mode of mod_wsgi, use daemon mode.
- Go watch my PyCon US 2012 talk. http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/
- Do some monitoring of your web application to determine how much memory it uses.
- Get an idea of what traffic volumes you need to handle.

Only once you have some real data about your applications memory requirements, how much load you need to handle and the response times of your application will you be able to work out the configuration and how much memory you need.

Answer (score 1):

- what is the operating system?
- how many connections are needed?
- what is the traffic that it needs to handle?

256MB does not seem realistic at first for CMS type of workload unless there is very little traffic and the operating system is striped down to the minimum needed.

Here is some data:
http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers

Comment: That benchmark should be ignored for determining memory use as the Apache configuration they used was completely flawed.

Comment: possibly. my point is more towards getting actual data and a baseline before asking the footprint for mod_wsgi in any unknown environment.